# How can I use WordPress functions in my stylesheet?

Tags: plugins, php, css, endpoints

I have my `style.php` file looking like this.

```
<?php  header('Content-Type: text/css');?>
#div{
    background:<?php  echo get_option('bgcolor');?>;
}
```

This does not work, but when I do this it works.

```
<?php  header('Content-Type: text/css');?>
#div{
    background: <?php  echo 'blue';?>;
}
```

What would be the problem?

This is the mainfile.php

```
 <?php 

    function test(){
    global get_option('bgcolor');?>

        <input type="text" id="bgcolor" name="post_popup_settings[bgcolor]" value="<?php echo get_option('bgcolor');?> " />
    <?php
}
    add_action('admin_head','test');
```

This is actually in the admin section.

Comment: How is WordPress called _in style.php?_

Comment: I used wp_enqueue_scripts();

Comment: wp_enqueue_style('my_style', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .'Includes/style.php');

Comment: I’m pretty sure you don’t use that in your `style.php`. If the style file is not called by WordPress no WordPress function is available.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

WordPress functions are available only if WordPress is loaded. If you call your `style.php` directly you cannot use a WordPress function.

One simple way to load WordPress for your PHP driven stylesheet is to add an endpoint to WordPress: a custom, reserved URL where you load your template file.

To get there you have to:

1. Register an endpoint on `'init'` with [`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint). Let’s name it `'phpstyle'`.
2. Hook into `'request'` and make sure the endpoint variable `'phpstyle'` is not empty if it is set. Read  Christopher Davis’ excellent [A (Mostly) Complete Guide to the WordPress Rewrite API](http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api) to understand what’s going on here.
3. Hook into `'template_redirect'` and deliver your file instead of the default template file `index.php`.

To keep things short I combined all three simple steps in *one* function in the following demo plugin.

**Plugin PHP Style**

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/*
 * Plugin Name: PHP Style
 * Description: Make your theme's 'style.php' available at '/phpstyle/'.
 */
add_action( 'init',              'wpse_54583_php_style' );
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_54583_php_style' );
add_filter( 'request',           'wpse_54583_php_style' );

function wpse_54583_php_style( $vars = '' )
{
    $hook = current_filter();

    // load 'style.php' from the current theme.
    'template_redirect' === $hook
        && get_query_var( 'phpstyle' )
        && locate_template( 'style.php', TRUE, TRUE )
        && exit;

    // Add a rewrite rule.
    'init' === $hook && add_rewrite_endpoint( 'phpstyle', EP_ROOT );

    // Make sure the variable is not empty.
    'request' === $hook
        && isset ( $vars['phpstyle'] )
        && empty ( $vars['phpstyle'] )
        && $vars['phpstyle'] = 'default';

    return $vars;
}
```

Install the plugin, visit `wp-admin/options-permalink.php` once to refresh the rewrite rules, and add a `style.php` to your theme.

**Sample `style.php`**

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
header('Content-Type: text/css;charset=utf-8');

print '/* WordPress ' . $GLOBALS['wp_version'] . " */\n\n";

print get_query_var( 'phpstyle' );
```

Now visit `yourdomain/phpstyle/`. Output:

```
/* WordPress 3.3.2 */

default
```

But if you go to `yourdomain/phpstyle/blue/` the output is:

```
/* WordPress 3.3.2 */

blue
```

So you can use the endpoint to deliver different stylesheets with one file depending on the value of `get_query_var( 'phpstyle' )`.

**Caveat**

This will slow down your site. WordPress has to be loaded **two times** for each visit. Don’t do it without aggressive caching.

Comment: +1 for porting this to WP. Short idea: `get_query_var( 'phpstyle' ) AND ! defined( 'SHORTINIT' ) AND define( 'SHORTINIT', true )` to speed things up... and if then all the needed functions are available...

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by loading the output via `admin-ajax.php`, but a better approach to that is to use WordPress `SHORTINIT` constant so you can load just what functions you need, but you will need to find and load `wp-load.php` to do this:

```
// send CSS Header
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

// faster load by reducing memory with SHORTINIT
define('SHORTINIT', true);

// recursively find WordPress load
function find_require($file,$folder=null) {
    if ($folder === null) {$folder = dirname(__FILE__);}
    $path = $folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;
    if (file_exists($path)) {require($path); return $folder;}
    else {
        $upfolder = find_require($file,dirname($folder));
        if ($upfolder != '') {return $upfolder;}
    }
}

// load WordPress core (minimal)
$wp_root_path = find_require('wp-load.php');
define('ABSPATH', $wp_root_path);
define('WPINC', 'wp-includes');
```

At this point you will **need** to be sure include whatever other `wp-includes` files you need to get your theme options - which will vary depending on your how you are saving and thus accessing those. (You will probably need to add more to this list so that you do not get fatal errors - but as you are going, the fatal errors will tell you which files you need to add.) eg.

```
include(ABSPATH.WPINC.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'version.php');
include(ABSPATH.WPINC.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'general-template.php');
include(ABSPATH.WPINC.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'link-template.php');
```

Then once you have all the functions you need, you can output the CSS using those functions... eg.

```
echo 'body {color:' . get_theme_mod('body_color') . ';}';
echo 'body {backgroundcolor:' . get_theme_mod('body_background_color') . ';}';
exit;
```

Then you can enqueue the file as normal, for example:

```
wp_enqueue_style('custom-css',trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()).'styles.php');
```

Comment: When adding your code to my files, it still says undefined. This is my code: http://pastebin.com/BJaUWX1x

Comment: you don't need the `../../` on the `wp-load.php` path, the function given will find it for you as is... but like I said you do need to find and include whatever files *you* need that have the functions you are using, eg. `get_background_image` is in `theme.php` etc... as you add to the CSS you may need more so you will need to learn how to find them to use this method effectively and reliably.