# How to change the default logout link on WordPress Admin

Tags: redirect, login, logout

I want to use another link for logout because I have `/wp-admin/*` protected with htpassword. Is there a way to do this? Something like creating a custom page like `site.com/logout` then use it as my new logout link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can filter `'logout_url'` and return a custom value if you are in the admin area:

```
add_filter( 'logout_url', 'wpse_58453_logout_url' );
function wpse_58453_logout_url( $default ) 
{
    // set your URL here
    return is_admin() ? 'http://example.com/custom' : $default;
}
```

Comment: But why do i get 404? I tried mysite.com/logout but i get 404 do i need to add some code on the end url?

Comment: Well, the target should exist somewhere. :) You could create a custom endpoint ([example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54612/73)).

Comment: What will do with the endpoint? I created a page called 'logout' and it just redirects it there what do i need to add on the logout page? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I am not sure if I still follow you … maybe that’s a separate question?

Comment: No same question. Here's the thing i followed your function added it on my custom function file then made it to "mysite.com/logout" the logout is a WordPress page. When i do `<?php echo wp_logout_url( ); ?>` it gives me a the right logout url which is mysite.com/logout but when i click on it it will just redirect me to the /logout WordPress page. Do i need to setup any code on my `/logout` page on wordpress?

Comment: Don’t understand. What’s wrong with a redirect to `/logout` if that’s the page you have set in the function?

Comment: `http://mysite.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=url` Currently this is the default logout URL for my site. I dont want to use this link. I want to use something like `http://mysite.com/logout` to do the logout action. I have no problem with redirect after logout thing. I hope you get my point. Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4114/discussion-between-wpleet-and-toscho)

Comment: I found the solution here: https://www.kmbytes.com/wordpress-logout-redirect-filter/

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add rewrite rule in your htaccess file like this.

```
RewriteRule ^logout/(.*) /wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me redirecting to the home page:

```
add_action('wp_logout','unlog');

function unlog(){
  wp_redirect( site_url() );
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. The accepted answer just did a redirect without a logout.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:
https://www.kmbytes.com/wordpress-logout-redirect-filter/

And it is working great!

```
add_filter( 'logout_url', 'my_logout_url' );
function my_logout_url( $url ) {
    $redirect = home_url();
    return $url.'&redirect_to='.$redirect;
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
    function wp_loginout( $redirect = '', $echo = true ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $link = '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_login_url( $redirect ) ) . '">' . __( 'Log in' ) . '</a>';
    } else {
        $link = '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_logout_url( $redirect ) ) . '">' . __( 'Log out' ) . '</a>';
    }
 
    if ( $echo ) {
        /**
         * Filters the HTML output for the Log In/Log Out link.
         *
         * @since 1.5.0
         *
         * @param string $link The HTML link content.
         */
        echo apply_filters( 'loginout', $link );
    } else {
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/general-template.php */
        return apply_filters( 'loginout', $link );
    }
}
```

Displays a link, which allows users to navigate to the Log In page to log in or log out depending on whether they are currently logged in.

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress Development community! This function is as advertised - however it does not actually address the question, which was asking how to change the destination of the link already available

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/252281)

Answer (score 0):

A very interesting solution is to create a Page "Logout" and then create the template of it in main folder of your theme by file `page-{your-logout-slug}.php`. And here is the simplest code of this page.

```
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : 
        wp_logout();
        wp_redirect(site_url());
    else : 
        wp_redirect(site_url());
    endif;
```

Add argument to `site_url()` of any slug or leave empty to be logged out to your home page. It's good because by using any php code you can do many things before you will be logged out.