# Hook to change Logout url

Tags: hooks, logout

I used this hook to replace the exit address .
Now, unfortunately, this hook does not work and I can not understand why

```
add_filter('logout_url', 'my_custom_logout_url');
        function my_custom_logout_url($force_reauth, $redirect=null){
        $logout_url = wp_nonce_url(site_url('logout.php')."?action=logout", 'log-out' );
        if (empty($redirect)) $redirect=home_url();
        $logout_url = add_query_arg('redirect_to', urlencode( $redirect )."", $logout_url );
        return $logout_url ;
        }
```

Comment: No need to regenerate the logout URL (the `$logout_url` part in your code) because the first parameter passed to your function is already the logout URL. Secondly, your `add_action()` call is missing the fourth parameter.

Comment: Previously, the hook worked correctly. After some update it stopped working. The hook replaced the links for users with wp-login.php/..... by logout.php/.....

Comment: Have a look at my answer.. that might help.

Comment: Or did you mean, you've got a `logout.php` page on your site (`example.com/logout.php`)? If so, how exactly the hook doesn't work? (PS: In my previous comment, I meant to say "add_filter")

Comment: I still see wp-login.php in exit link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>There's *no need to regenerate the logout URL* (the `$logout_url` part in your code) because the first parameter passed to your function is already the logout URL.</strike>

<strike>So basically, just rename that `$force_reauth` to `$logout_url` and remove the `$logout_url = wp_nonce_url( ... );`:</strike>

```php
function my_custom_logout_url($logout_url, $redirect=null){ // rename the $force_reauth
    // And remove this:
    //$logout_url = wp_nonce_url(site_url('logout.php')."?action=logout", 'log-out' );
```

<strike>Secondly,</strike> your `add_filter()` call is missing the fourth parameter (which is the number of arguments passed to your function):

```php
add_filter('logout_url', 'my_custom_logout_url', 10, 2); // like this
add_filter('logout_url', 'my_custom_logout_url');        // not this
```

### UPDATE

If you actually did mean to set the logout URL to `example.com/logout.php` (note the `logout.php`), then your code is actually good (except the `add_filter()` thing above). But if your code is still showing `wp-login.php`, then it's possible another code (maybe a plugin) is filtering/changing the logout URL. And in that case, you can change the callback *priority* to a greater number like `20`:

```php
// The third parameter is the callback priority.
add_filter('logout_url', 'my_custom_logout_url', 20, 2); // the priority is now 20
```

Comment: `add_filter('logout_url', 'my_custom_logout_url', 20, 2);` that help me. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.. I was actually about to ask you to change the callback priority.. and I updated my answer for completeness. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I created a page named "**log-out**"

And then, in page-log-out.php I added this (the cookies lines can be avoided)

```php
wp_logout();
$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;
setcookie("user_role", '', time()-1000, '/', $domain, false, true);
setcookie("user_id", '', time()-1000, '/', $domain, false, true);
setcookie("full_name", '', time()-1000, '/', $domain, false, true);
wp_redirect(home_url());
```

Hope it works for you

I find this too, check there

[How to change the default logout link on WordPress Admin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58453/how-to-change-the-default-logout-link-on-wordpress-admin)