# How can I call a thumbnail/featured image to be a background image?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I activated the post thumbnail by putting this in the `functions.php`:

`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails');`

And this in the `loop.php`:

`<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array ('class' => 'rollover')) ; ?>`

And voila, the featured image appears on the main page, hopefully with the class of "rollover."

But what I want to do is turn this into a sprite. On my static HTML markup I wrote:

```
a.rollover: {
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:url(images/oldtable.jpg);
    arollover:hover {background-position:-300px 0;
}
```

It works, but how do I make this dynamic (is that the word?) What do I substitute for the url so that the background url changes for each thumbnail?  I tried this and it didn't work:

`background:url(<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src());`

Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: you can not run `<?php ?>` in `.css`

Comment: See also: [How can I use WordPress functions in my stylesheet?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54583/how-can-i-use-wordpress-functions-in-my-stylesheet/54612#54612)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a WordPress related, Anyway here is tip -

You can not call a `<?php .. ?>` function into your `style.css` file. Instead set the background inline just as shown in this example, and apple styling.

```
<div style="background: url('<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src(); ?>');">
   // blah blah ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a trick :)

create a css.php in your theme, and use `<?php get_template_part('css'); ?>`
when you need in your templates.

in your css.php you can use call to wp_get_attachment_image_src(), etc... define $vars for your colors (theme options) and so on...

Comment: with this trick you can keep css abstraction of your code, and reuse this css

Comment: ...or you can just switch to LESS (there's WP-Less on GitHub).

Answer (score 0):

I could NOT get the sprite to work. I ended up using two separate images, positioning them on top of each other, and styling their opacity based on the rollover state.