# Whats the proper way to use a php stylesheet in a wordpress theme?

Tags: php, css, wp-enqueue-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use WordPress functions in my stylesheet?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54583/how-can-i-use-wordpress-functions-in-my-stylesheet)

I have a file, custom.php, thats basically a stylesheet with php variables for the styles. I used [this guide](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/csscolor/) to make it but Im not sure how to use the style sheet in my theme.
Here is my /styles/custom.php:

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: text/css"); 
?>
div{background-color:<?php echo "red" ?>;}
```

and my functions.php file has this:

```
$root=get_bloginfo('template_directory'); 
wp_enqueue_style("custom", $root."/styles/custom.php");
```

So the custom.php file should be rendered as a stylesheet right? But my wordpress site doesnt load the file contents. When I look at the source code via firebug and expand the custom.php file all I see is:

```
Reload the page to get source for: http://samsung/wordpress/wp-content/themes/kjd/styles/custom.php?ver=3.4.1
```

This is on my dev machine running Ubuntu 12.04, LAMP and Wordpress 3.4.1

Comment: Is this `custom.php` file a part of you theme?

Comment: What do you mean? It's in my theme directory and Im calling the file in functions.php with wp_enqueue_style

Comment: If its a part of your theme, means it has the `get_header()` function call, which automatically enqueues the `style.css`. If it's not a part of your theme, then why do you need the `style.css` on it?

Comment: No see, this is custom.php is basically a CSS file that uses php variables for the styles. It's not a page template or anything. Edited for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you need, but take a look.

```
// Can be put into function.php

if ( !is_admin() ) { 
    add_action( "wp_enqueue_scripts", "enqueue_scripts", 11 ); 
}
function enqueue_scripts() {

    // Theme CSS (style.css)
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-file', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css',false,'1.0','all' );

    // JS
    wp_register_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/your-script.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script' );

}
```

Or use ...

```
// Used to include PHP
include_once(TEMPLATEPATH . 'script.php');
```

Sometimes it helps to also tell the .htaccess file how files should be handled. Throw this in your .htaccess file.

```
# handler for phpsuexec..
<FilesMatch "\.(css|style)$">
 SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I have whats in the first part of what you have, thats what Im using to send my stylesheets to the wp_head()  but what I need to do is get my php driven stylesheet to work. I edited my question for clarity

Comment: I have updated the code above.

Comment: ahhh ok cool yeah, I just found [this site](http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/) and at the bottom it says to use `<FilesMatch "^.*?style.*?$">
SetHandler php5-script
</FilesMatch>`   Which KIND OF works, it conflicts with my other style sheets. It seems that if there is content in my main style sheet then it completely ignores this new custom one.

Comment: hmm ok so I think it's working now. the custom.css file has to have html{} in it. But it doesnt accept php variables

Comment: Did you try the .htaccess snippet?

Comment: Yeah, that produced the same results I was getting before but I found a work around. Ill post the answer in a bit after I've made sure its the route Im going to take. Thanks tho!

Comment: What did you end up doing?