# Custom user profile URLs

Tags: url-rewriting, users, front-end, profiles

I have created a page "profile" that when visited with get variable of user id like:

```
http://example.com/profile/?uid=1
```

Then it will display the profile details of user id `1`. Now I want to rewrite …

```
http://example.com/profile/?uid=1
```

… to …

```
http://example.com/profile/admin
```

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

1. [Create an endpoint for `EP_ROOT`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54583/how-can-i-use-wordpress-functions-in-my-stylesheet/54612#54612) named `profile`.
2. In your callback handler use [`get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'profile' ) )`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_user_by/) to find the user data.
3. Create a template file `profile.php` and use [`locate_template( 'profile.php', TRUE )`](http://queryposts.com/function/locate_template/) to load it.
4. In your template show the user data.