# How can I process all requests for a given directory in a URL with my plugin?

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, urls

I'd like to pass all requests for a given directory using a plugin or template file.

For instance, all of the following requests would be sent to the plugin:

```
mysite.com/directory/blah
mysite.com/directory/foo/bar
mysite.com/directory/another/one/here
```

I would then like to do some custom processing on the "blah", "foo bar", and "another one here" data, outputting resulting content.

I've looked into rewrite rules, but I can't figure out if this is just used for "prettifying" URLs or if it can be used for more complex processing.

**Edit:** I do not believe I need an endpoint.  I don't want to add an action to some other post types.  For instance, let's say /directory/ is retrieving content from another server.

Comment: Why do you not want to use an endpoint? They are made exactly for this situation. Please add an explanation to your question.

Comment: The example that is given for endpoints are things like tracebacks.  As I understand it, that might mean I would want something like /post/01/12/2004/traceback/ to give a traceback for that particular post.  On the contrary, the plugin will have nothing to do with particular bits of content in Wordpress.

Comment: Nope, you can register endpoints for almost any URL, including the root URL. See [this example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54612/73).