# PHP in CSS file?

Tags: php, css, directory

so I have this in my CSS ...

```
  #mainnav li:after {
content: url('images/nav-divider.png');
}
```

obviously I need to have it link to 'bloginfo('template_directory'); /images/nav-divider.png' instead but how do I link that correctly seeing as there is PHP in it?

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: This is a **PHP/CSS** question, that is not *specific to WordPress*.

Comment: You could accomplish it using [`wp_add_inline_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style) to alter the `#mainnav li:after` style once your stylesheets have loaded.

Comment: Have you seen [How can I use WordPress functions in my stylesheet?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54583/how-can-i-use-wordpress-functions-in-my-stylesheet)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`wp_add_inline_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style).

Let's assume you enqueue your css like so

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_style' );

function add_my_style() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'my_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/mystyle.css' );
}
```

Then you can change the function like so:

```
function add_my_style() {

   wp_enqueue_script( 'my_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/mystyle.css' );

   $style = "#mainnav li:after { content: url('{theme_url}/images/nav-divider.png'); }";
   $style .= "#another-example { content: url('{theme_url}/images/example.png'); }";

   $data = str_replace( '{theme_url}', get_template_directory_uri(), $style );

   wp_add_inline_style( 'my_style', $data )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a relative path. For example, if your stylesheet is in `/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/mystyles.css` and your image is in `/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/nav-divider.png`, then your path would be `../images/nav-divider.png`.